# List all the pairs $(x,y)$ s.t. $x^2 - y^2 = 2020$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

List all of the pairs $(x,y) \in \mathbb{Z}^2$ s.t. $^2 - ^2 = 2020$.

The prime factorization of $2020$ is $2^2 \cdot 5 \cdot 101$. I used the fact that there exists a solution $(x,y) \in \mathbb{Z}^2$ to the Diophantine equation $x^2 - y^2 = n$ if and only if $n$ is odd or $n$ is a multiple of $4$. Since $n$ is a multiple of $4$, there exist a solution.

I know there is a solution but I am neither able to obtain the number of solution nor able to get the list all the pairs $(x,y)$.

Comment: It's often easier to turn addition/subtraction problems into multiplication problems. Remember that $x^2 -y^2 =(x+y)(x-y)$.

Comment: I didn't get that

Comment: Use the prime factorization that you found and see how you can combine them into two factors.

Comment: For every pair of (positive or negative) divisors of $2020$, you will get one and only one pair $(x,y)$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The number of integral points on the hyperbola $x^2 - y^2 = (2000)^2$ is](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3777661/the-number-of-integral-points-on-the-hyperbola-x2-y2-20002-is)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint

$x+y,x-y$ have the same parity as $x+y+x-y$ or $x+y-(x-y)$ is even

Now as $2020$ is even, both must be even

$$\implies\dfrac{x+y}2\cdot\dfrac{x-y}2=\dfrac{2020}4$$

Now if $x,y>0$ $$x+y>x-y$$

As $505=1\cdot505=5\cdot101,$

$\dfrac{x-y}2=1$ or $5$

Comment: Is there any way we can calculate the number of possible solutions?

Comment: Please can you explain in more detail!

Comment: @John, Where is your confusion

Comment: Never mind I got it

Answer (score 1):

$x^2 - y^2 = (x+y)(x-y) = 2020 = 2^2 \cdot 5 \cdot 101$

So $$(x+y) = 202$$

(think about it)

and $$(x-y) = 10$$

Yielding $x=106$ and $y = 96$ as one pair.  Follow the logic to find the other(s) pair(s), i.e., other solutions to $x+y=...$.

Comment: That's not the only pair that satisfy the equation.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility, besides $(x,y)=(106,96)$ listed in another answer,

is $x+y=1010$ and $x-y=2$, yielding $x=506$ and $y=504$.

Of course, if $(x,y)$ is a solution, then so is $(-x,y)$, $(x,-y)$, and $(-x,-y)$.

Comment: This implies there will be 8 solutions for this problem right?

Comment: That is correct, @John